# Debugging SWIG %ignore

Tags: c++, swig

I'm trying to get SWIG to `%ignore` a symbol like `MyNamespace::SubNamespace::MyClass::operator->()`. I've tried a million different combinations of `%ignore`:

- `%ignore operator->;`
- `%ignore operator ->;`
- `%ignore operator ->();`
- `%ignore *::operator->;`
- `%ignore MyNamespace::SubNamespace::MyClass::operator->;`

Hell even `%ignore MyNamespace::SubNamespace::MyClass;` doesn't seem to do anything. In every case I get this error:

```
...MyFile.hpp:267: Warning 508: Declaration of 'operator <' shadows declaration accessible via operator->(),
...MyFile.hpp:192: Warning 508: previous declaration of 'operator <'.
```

It's caused by [this SWIG code](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Source/Modules/allocate.cxx#L402), which seems to be something to do with smart pointers. However it looks from the code like `%ignore`ing the `operator->()` should remove the warning. In any case ignoring the entire class should.

So my question is, is there any way to debug `%ignore`. As far as I can see it looks like you have to just keep trying combinations until it works. Is there a way to print out SWIG's list of symbols? The code doesn't look like it has any logging facility.

Comment: I have a similar situation and using %ignore MyNamespace::SubNamespace::MyClass::operator->; does help to get rid of .__deref__() generation. Your problem is more likely caused by 'operator <' than 'operator->'.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't find an option for `%ignore` specifically, but there are various `-debug-...` command line options. In particular `-debug-symbols` lead me to find that `operator->()` is `%rename`d to `__deref__` in `swig.swg` which is included by default in all files.

I tried `%ignore __deref__;` and some variants but that doensn't work.

I even eventually modified the code to detect `%ignore`s (hint:

```
/* Create a name applying rename/namewarn if needed */
static String *apply_rename(String *newname, int fullname, String *prefix, String *name) {
  String *result = 0;
  if (newname && Len(newname)) {
    if (Strcmp(newname, "$ignore") == 0) {
        printf("Renaming to ignore: %s\n", Char(name));
      result = Copy(newname);
```

) but none of those names seem to have namespaces. In fact, the warning about two `operator<`'s are in different classes (although one is a friend of the other) and as far as I can tell SWIG is just looking up if there are any other `operator<`'s. Could be a namespace bug.